# Has there been any analysis on LIGO data looking for a 24 hour frequency?

Tags: spacetime, ligo

The reason I ask this is because it seems like it would be a simple analysis to run with all the data we have and it would tell us if the land-based LIGO detectors pick up anything depending on our orientation to the sun. I would expect if there is an effect it would be very small.

The reason:
With the Sun turning millions of tons of mass directly into energy every second I expect a space-time flow would be moving past the Earth. Due to our radius from the Sun, this flow would be incredibly slow, perhaps undetectable.

Comment: There are 24 hour variations in signal to noise, and the analysis is oriented in eliminating noise. see fig4 here http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0509041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sun's gravitational effect on things on earth, as compared to that of earth's gravitational effect is negligible.
2. Amount of mass lost by sun in a second is negligible as compared to sun's total mass.

Therefore, the change in gravity (space time) every moment, due to sun's mass reduction is really really negligible.

Even though the minute change would take place in one leg of LIGO, before it happens in the other leg, I do not think it is feasible to detect this change ever.

Actually, then you can also say that one leg of LIGO is closer to sun as compared to the other LEG, so, why does LIGO not detect that difference in gravity.

There would be many other events that would cause more change in gravity than this and remain undetected by LIGO.

It is crazy crazy crazy small, so, I do not think any such analysis is necessary for any purpose.

Comment: The point you need to make, if indeed it can be made, is that any affects cannot produce 1 part in $10^{20}$ changes at the detector. For that you need some Maths, not hyperbole.

Comment: I am also down voting, because the gravitational field of the Sun at the Earth is $6\times 10^{-4}g$ and because you cannot compare a rate of mass loss with a mass; they have different dimensions.

Comment: Maybe you can enlighten me then, I thought what LIGO detected was a wave in space-time due to very massive objects moving really fast (closer and further from us). A similar effect wave be detected if a mass were to appear and disappear really fast, I know this is impossible.

Comment: What I am asking is, can we detect space-time fluctuations when mass turns to energy? I would say this would has similarities to the two scenarios above with a mass moving away really fast as well as if a mass were to disappear. 

I know the effect would be very small but so were the g-waves LIGO detected.

Comment: @RobJeffries: You can find time taken by light to travel from one leg of LIGO, to the other leg (assuming one leg is facing sun)). Mass loss by sun during that amount of time, divided by total mass of sun (10^9 / 10^33 for one second). Multiply that number by the number you mentioned above. That will give you 1 part in much more than 10^20.

Comment: @Joe: Those are electromagnetic fluctuations, not space time fluctuations. Energy is equivalent to mass as far as space time is concerned.

Comment: @RobJeffries: I edited the comparison line.

Comment: 10^9 / 10^33 for one second is incorrect, corrected is .5 * 10^9 / 10^30.